# How to save a file from Qrc to application directory

Tags: qt, qfile, qdir, qt5.15

I am using Qt 5.15.1.

If I have a file in in my Qt app's qrc file, is it possible to save the file into application's directory so that I can use that file as a normal file on the file system?

```
QFile my_file(":/data/file.txt");
QDir my_app_dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

in above code, how can I save `my_file` into `my_app_dir`?

**Environment:**
MacOS Catalina
Qt: Commercial version 5.15.1

Answer (score 0):

You just have to copy the content:

```
QFile my_file(":/data/file.txt");
QDir my_app_dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QString new_path = my_app_dir.absoluteFilePath("file.txt");
if(!my_file.copy(new_path)){
    qDebug() << my_file.error() << my_file.errorString();
}
```

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer That should work on any OS since it's a trivial task, have you tried it? It would be good if you try the code before asking.

Comment: I tried it. It hangs my app. Hence was wondering if it has permission issues on macOS Catalina.

Comment: It depends on where applicationDirPath() is located, if you don't have permissions to write then you will have problems. Note: It is good to point out the characteristics of the environment in your post such as the OS for example

Comment: Sorry. I mentioned the environment now. But I am trying this on Android to get the factor of file permission thing out of my way. If this code works on Android, I will accept it. The file permission thing is a separate problem.

Comment: `my_file.copy` always returns false!

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer And what error does it indicate? For this I have placed the qDebug().

Comment: `Cannot open :/data/file.txt for input` it says in the error. I am pretty sure that the qrc file is there. I copied the file path by right clicking on the file in the qrc. So, the path should also be correct. I wonder whats wrong

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer What do you get when you run `qDebug() << ;QDir(":/data/").entryList();` or `qDebug() << QFileInfo(":/data/file.txt").exists();`